# How to Add Watermark in The Middle Bottom

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a watermark in a pdf file in the center bottom of pdf file .. I tried many ways but i did not figure out how it's works exactly to select the location of watermark.

Anyway here is the code:

```
string filepath = @"~/Images/logo-01.png";
                iTextSharp.text.Image pageIn = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath(filepath));


                pageIn.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                pageIn.ScaleToFit(150, 150);
                pageIn.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
                pageIn.SetAbsolutePosition((PageSize.A4.Width - pageIn.ScaledWidth) / 2, (PageSize.A4.Height - pageIn.ScaledHeight) / 10);
```

Again i want to make the watermark position in the max center bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [GroupDocs.Watermark for .NET](https://products.groupdocs.com/watermark/net) that allows controlling the horizontal and vertical position of the watermark in the documents. This is how you can add watermark at the bottom of the pages in a PDF document:

```
using (PdfDocument doc = Document.Load<PdfDocument>("D:\\sample.pdf"))
{
        // Add text watermark
        TextWatermark watermark = new TextWatermark("Protected Document", new Font("Arial", 8));
        watermark.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        watermark.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        doc.AddWatermark(watermark);

        // Add image watermark
        ImageWatermark imageWatermark = new ImageWatermark("D:\\watermark.png");
        imageWatermark.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        imageWatermark.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        doc.AddWatermark(imageWatermark);

        // Save document
        doc.Save("D:\\output.pdf");
}
```

*Disclosure: I work as a Developer Evangelist at GroupDocs.*

Comment: Hi Usman please take urgent a look to the part [if some (but not all)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)